# Подключение джойстика в Qt (Windows)

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно добавить в проект управление джойстиком. Наткнулся на библиотеку [QJoysticks](https://frc-utilities.github.io/documentation/qjoysticks/index.html). На гите лежит [пример](https://github.com/alex-spataru/QJoysticks/tree/master/examples/JoystickList) с использованием этой библиотеки.

Когда запускаю его, джойстик распознается. Но когда начинаю писать свой код, программа его не видит .

Пример кода:

```
QJoysticks *joy = QJoystecks::getInstance();
QStringList name_list = joy->deviceNames();
foreach(QString name, name_list){
ui->comboBox->addItem(name);
}
```

Выводя в дебаге `name_list` вижу, что он тоже пуст.
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgamepad-index.html не фурычит?

Comment: Нет, даже примеры, которые с ним есть, не работают